# Azure DevOps multiple Docker containers on the same Agent (VM)

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have to use Azure DevOps agent on the VM because that VM is located in special network (so can't use AKS, etc)

VM has Docker installed and pipeline has job with container specified

How can I execute multiple Docker containers on the same VM (agent) to run jobs in parallel

Comment: You can try to run agent in docker container.Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way that I've found is to execute the following bash script on system startup (add `@reboot /root/ados-agents-start.sh` via `crontab -e`):

```
for run in {1..3}
do
  docker run -d -e VSTS_ACCOUNT='kagarlickij' -e VSTS_POOL='Self-Hosted' -e VSTS_TOKEN='a***q' mcr.microsoft.com/azure-pipelines/vsts-agent:ubuntu-16.04-docker-18.06.1-ce > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```